# How to add a button to a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, matlab-guide

I want to add a button to this code that will close me the window and save the picture as i rotated it.

```
function rotationGUI(a)
    I = imread(a);

    %# c
    hFig = figure('menu','none');
    hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);

    uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', 'Value',0, 'Min',0,...
        'Max',360, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./360, ...
        'Position',[150 5 300 20], 'Callback',@slider_callback) 
    hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[290 28 20 15], 'String','0');
    %# show image
    imshow(I, 'Parent',hAx)
    %# Callback function
    function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata)
        angle = round(get(hObj,'Value'));        %# get rotation angle in degrees
        imshow(imrotate(I,angle), 'Parent',hAx)  %# rotate image
        set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(angle))       %# update text
    end
function ok_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 set(hTxt, 'String','save')
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few hacks here and there, here it goes -

**Main function**

```
function rotationGUI(a)
I = imread(a);

%# c
hFig = figure('menu','none');
hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);

hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[290 28 20 15], 'String','0');
uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', 'Value',0, 'Min',0,...
    'Max',360, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./360, ...
    'Position',[150 5 300 20], 'Callback',{@slider_callback,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig})

uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','Save and Close',...
    'Position',[10 20 120 40],'Callback',{@ok_Callback,I,hTxt,hFig});

%# show image
imshow(I, 'Parent',hAx)
%# Callback function

return;
```

**Associated function -1**

```
function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig)

global Irot
angle = round(get(hObj,'Value'));        %# get rotation angle in degrees
Irot = imrotate(I,angle);
imshow(Irot, 'Parent',hAx)  %# rotate image
set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(angle))       %# update text

return;
```

**Associated function -2**

```
function ok_Callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hTxt,hFig)

global Irot

set(hTxt, 'String','save')

[filename, pathname] = uiputfile('*.jpg', 'Save Image as');
imwrite(Irot,strcat(pathname,filename));

delete(hFig);
return;
```

**Edit 1:** If you would like to save the  rotated image as the original image, that is overwrite to it, use these changes -

Edit function `rotationGUI` -

```
uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','Save and Close',...
    'Position',[10 20 120 40],'Callback',{@ok_Callback,I,hTxt,hFig,a});
```

Edit function `ok_callback` -

```
function ok_callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hTxt,hFig,path1)

global Irot

set(hTxt, 'String','save')
imwrite(Irot,path1);

delete(hFig);
end
```

Comment: @user2347210 A good practice to end a function is to use `RETURN` instead of `END`.

Comment: and if i whant to save it on the origenal picture what i need to change ?

Comment: @user2347210 Check out Edit 1.

Comment: TNX!! you help me a lot

Comment: One last question friend... i try to get output from the function the final angle with i choose to rotate .. can you help ?

Comment: If you would like to do all that, I would suggest using GUIDE instead of `uicontrols` - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/gui-building-basics.html

Comment: I dont find there a answear...maybe i doesnt explain myself good.. what i said that in the begging i write function [**x**]=rotationGUI(a)... if i rotate the picture by angel 90 .. it will retorn to 90 (with verible x)... what i ask , what x need to be

Comment: Quick hack - Define a global `angle` in `slider_callback` and `rotationGUI` and define the syntax as `function angle = rotationGUI(a)`